# comecei a utilizar o intellij eu quero saber com rodar minha aplicação de console

Tags: java, ide, intellij

olá comecei a programa em java a pouco tempo, e um amigo que é mais experiente me recomendou usar o **Intellij** como ide, já configurei a ide de maneira básica,meus códigos ja rodam utilizando o **javac** pelo **CMD**, porem não consigo rodar meus códigos em console dentro da **ide**, tentei escolher diverso tipo de templates dentro da plataforma, porem nenhum funciono ou me pareceu apropriado para meu código. o codigo em questão é esse :

```
import java.util.Scanner; //1. importando a classe scanner 
public class Exemplo1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
//2. instanciando e criando um objeto scanner 
Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

int i, n;

System.out.printf("informe o numero para a tabuada:\n");
n = ler.nextInt(); //3.1 entrada de dados (lendo um valor inteiro)

System.out.printf("\n+--resultado--+\n");
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) { 
    System.out.printf("| %2d * %d = %2d |\n", i, n, (i*n));
}   
System.out.printf("+----------------+\n");
}
```

}
 aqui o codigo que eu gostaria de rodar pelo intellij

gostaria de saber se é possivel fazer isso e como se configurar a ide de maneira apropriada

Comment: No básico do básico, você cria um projeto java no intellij, define o JDK a ser usado, cria um package, cria uma classe main como você criou e depois clica em run. Você já tentou usar o hello world java intellij? Link: [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#]

Comment: obrigado, eu percebi que meu jdk não estava instalado corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Outro ponto que seu código não irá rodar em nenhuma IDE, seu código precisa ajustar o bloco do método da classe,  a classe instanciada Scanner e os demais argumentos com a declaração das variáveis e os prints de saida no console, ficaram fora do bloco  do método main{ }.
Sobre executar o Run no seu código, ajuste o JDK e prepare seu ambiente para poder executar de forma correta:
Faz assim, no IntelliJ, vá para a estrutura do projeto (ctrl + alt + shift + s) e adicione o seu JDK, que já esteja instalado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]